# Mapping image (Frontside-Backside) onto a sphere in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a question regarding the Three JS.

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/syildiz/fk8thLsq/17/

I want to creat an eye that follows the mouse movements. The images i upload are visible in the background at the same time and there is a white line at the joining of the image.

In the example, I have added pictures I want to use in the front and back. I want to use the image at the front, in the back and the image (or color) at the back, in the front. I also want to get rid of the white line, how can i do this?

```
Frontside Image https://image.ibb.co/mmsJ7J/logo_front.png

Backside Image https://image.ibb.co/bE8i7J/logo_back.png (or color)
```

I am still fairly new with Three JS, i would appreciate if you could help me on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign two materials to the object, one for the front and one for the back. Then you need to set the `materialIndex` of each face, so the faces know which material to use.

```
// use material array to apply multiple materials
var material = [
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "https://image.ibb.co/mmsJ7J/logo_front.png")
  }),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "https://image.ibb.co/bE8i7J/logo_back.png")
  })
];

// in your faces loop, set materialIndex according to front or back side of geometry
if (v1.z < 0)
    faces[i].materialIndex = 1;

// after loop, set groupsNeedUpdate -> "Set to true if a face3 materialIndex has been updated."
geometry.groupsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Regarding the white line: this is because you are at the very edge of the texture (respectively the opaque edge of the circle). I added some offset, so the texture will slightly overlap.

```
var max = geometry.boundingBox.max.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1)),
    min = geometry.boundingBox.min.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(-1,-1,-1));

// If the radius of the sphere is smaller, you should also set a smaller offset.
// in this example it's 1:60, which is ok.
```

Here's a snippet (or have a look at your updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fk8thLsq/36/)

```js
//Setup:

var container = document.querySelector('#container');


var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
var WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

var VIEW_ANGLE = 40;
var ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
var NEAR = 0.1;
var FAR = 1000;

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 50);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = null;
scene.add(camera);

container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var RADIUS = 200;
var SEGMENTS = 50;
var RINGS = 50;


var group = new THREE.Group();
scene.add(group);

var material = [
 new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "https://image.ibb.co/mmsJ7J/logo_front.png" ),
    overdraw: 0
 }),
 new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "https://image.ibb.co/bE8i7J/logo_back.png" ),
    overdraw: 0
 })
];

scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2));

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.2);
camera.add(light);

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(60, 64, 32);

geometry.computeBoundingBox();

var max = geometry.boundingBox.max.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1)),
    min = geometry.boundingBox.min.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(-1,-1,-1));
    
var offset = new THREE.Vector2(0 - min.x, 0 - min.y);
var range = new THREE.Vector2(max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y);
var faces = geometry.faces;

geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {

    var v1 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].a],
        v2 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].b],
        v3 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].c];
        
    if (v1.z < 0)
      faces[i].materialIndex = 1;

    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
        new THREE.Vector2((v1.x + offset.x) / range.x, (v1.y + offset.y) / range.y),
        new THREE.Vector2((v2.x + offset.x) / range.x, (v2.y + offset.y) / range.y),
        new THREE.Vector2((v3.x + offset.x) / range.x, (v3.y + offset.y) / range.y)
    ]);
}

geometry.groupsNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

group.add(mesh);
group.position.z = -270;

var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
pointLight.position.x = -100;
pointLight.position.y = 0;
pointLight.position.z = 200;

scene.add(pointLight);


function update() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

requestAnimationFrame(update);

function animationBuilder(direction) {
    return function animateRotate() {
        switch (direction) {
            case 'up':
                group.rotation.x -= 0.2;
                break;
            case 'down':
                group.rotation.x += 0.2;
                break;
            case 'left':
                group.rotation.y -= 0.2;
                break;
            case 'right':
                group.rotation.y += 0.2;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}

var animateDirection = {
    up: animationBuilder('up'),
    down: animationBuilder('down'),
    left: animationBuilder('left'),
    right: animationBuilder('right')
};

function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        animateDirection.up();
    } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        animateDirection.down();
    } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        animateDirection.left();
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        animateDirection.right();
    }
}

document.onkeydown = checkKey;

var lastMove = [window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2];

function rotateOnMouseMove(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var moveX = e.clientX - lastMove[0];
    var moveY = e.clientY - lastMove[1];

    group.rotation.y += moveX * .004;
    group.rotation.x += moveY * .004;

    lastMove[0] = e.clientX;
    lastMove[1] = e.clientY;
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', rotateOnMouseMove);
```

```css
body{margin:0;background:#ddd;}
.logo{position:absolute;top:10px;width:100px;height:100px;background-size:100% auto;background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.front{left:10px;background-image:url("https://image.ibb.co/mmsJ7J/logo_front.png")}
.back{left:120px;background-image:url("https://image.ibb.co/bE8i7J/logo_back.png")}
```

```html
<div class="logo front"></div>
<div class="logo back"></div>
<div id="container" width="100vw" height="100vh"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
```

You will notice that there is still a seam between both materials. Maybe you should use a plain color for your textures and achieve the slightly specular behaviour by setting the material properties accordingly.